# Error: Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, ssis, manifest

I created a Deployment Manifest for SSIS in SQL Server 2008 R2.  It used to work just fine, but I recently installed SQL 2012 on my machine and now I’m getting this error when trying to run the deployment manifest:

> Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported.

The server I’m deploying the SSIS packages onto is not my machine, but the deployment manifest used to run just fine before.  Also, the server I'm deploying it to is 2008 R2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From a command prompt (Start->Run cmd.exe) type `where dtsinstall.exe` and update your question with the results of that

Comment: I tried dtsinstall.exe "M:\IT\Projects\LAR\Staging\Ticket #55388\Adding Lien To Override Table\Load Override Data.SSISDeploymentManifest" and that did the trick.  I tried it before, but without the directory path to the file and when I tried I got this error "You need to specify the full path to a SSIS deployment manifest file." and I just gave up.  ...tried with the path this time and it worked.  Thank you so much, billinkc.

Comment: Hi Lenka, I'm having same problem, could you please explain the trick step by step? - as an answer.